# Ricoh Streamline NX, password reset

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-printer, sql

Recently, my IT department implemented RICOH STREAMLINE NX V3 for LDAP MANAGEMENT.  We changed the password but it doesn't match and I need to reset it.

We are using a Windows Server 2012 with IIS and a local sql server.

This is the login in the system:
[image: this is the login in the system]

This is the sql database:
[image: this is the sql database]

Comment: This sounds like something you probably want to have your IT department fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear community members,

The post is a bit old but since I ended up in here, I would like to share my experience and how I/we was/were able to solve the problem (continuing from the step that the post requester had mentioned).

Apparently, the number of tries on a single account is set to a specific number (by default but can be changed). In our case (which is by default), it was "6". Using SQL management studio (like what the post requester did) is the key component towards solving the issue. The only difference is that we picked up another table which is “auth_internal” instead of “access_account”.

[The "auth_internal" table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdKFs.png)

With this said, and after many tests and fields data-changing, we ended up knowing that when doing “6” successive false attempts, the account is disabled. Disabled is represented by filling the “authint_disabled_date” column and thus: if it contains “NULL” then the account is enabled, if it contains something else like the date in when the account reached the 6th failed attempt then the account is considered to be disabled.

[The "authint_disabled_date" column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eFKG.png)

As a consequence, returning the “NULL” value for the appropriate user in its column “authint_disabled_date” seems to be solving the problem (do not forget to make “execute” to let the effects take place).

Also, you may exploit the second account (RicohAtRemoteOperator). If you are lucky and it happens for the password to be by default, you will be able to log into the system and restore the main admin account without being forced to use other solutions like the SQL management studio (see the next image). You can make a simple search to find it.

[The default password of "RicohAtRemoteOperator"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWGCK.png)

At last, I recommend creating at least one other admin account that can’t be easily predicted and, hence, be able to avoid someone making many attempts on the well-known “admin” account.

Good luck,

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the post by MB_7 about the values to change to unlock the account, if you can't remember the passwords you can blank them by changing one of the entries to:
631C5EA091C0A6AA1B8D13EB627F3E75
putting that in place for one of the passwords will change it to a blank password and then prompt you to change it when you successfully log in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).